# Exchange server blocks emails with embedded images

Tags: .net, image, exchange-server

Unfortunately due to an update made by our exchange server provider, we cannot send emails with embedded images anymore.

As soon as we send the email, we receive this error: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
If we remove the image from the email, everything works just fine.
Is there any work around to this problem?

Our c# code:

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");
LinkedResource imagelink;
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(Body, "<img.*?src=\"cid:(.*?)\"");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(match.Groups[1].Value));

    myHttpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    using (myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        receivedStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        MemoryStream streamReceivedCopy = new MemoryStream();                       
        ImageUtils.CopyStream(receivedStream,streamReceivedCopy);
        var imageType = ImageUtils.GetImageMIMEType(streamReceivedCopy);
        streamReceivedCopy.Position = 0;
        imagelink = new LinkedResource(streamReceivedCopy, imageType);
        imagelink.ContentId = match.Groups[1].Value;
        imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
    }
}
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

We use then the .net SmtpClient to send the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to track down the error: it was just an old library being deployed causing the error.
The old library was missing these lines of code

```
myHttpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

sorry! :(